# How to export SVG as PNG using canvg.js and Canvas

Tags: javascript, vue.js

We are trying to export SVG picture as PNG using canvg.js but when we click the button **"Take a screenshot"** the console shows error **"vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: SVG2PNG is not defined"**". Here is the button that calls function **"tipka()"**, I followed this example: "https://jsgao0.wordpress.com/2016/06/02/export-svg-as-png-using-canvg-js-and-canvas/".

```
<input id='downloadBtn' @click="tipka()" type='button' style="margin-top:500px; position:absolute" value='Download'/>
```

Here is the script file:

```
import Canvg from "canvg";

export default {
  methods: {
    SVG2PNG(svg, callback) {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); // Create a Canvas element.
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // For Canvas returns 2D graphic.
      var data = svg.outerHTML; // Get SVG element as HTML code.
      canvg(canvas, data); // Render SVG on Canvas.
      callback(canvas); // Execute callback function.
    },
    generateLink(fileName, data) {
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.download = fileName;
      link.href = data;
      return link;
    },

    tipka() {
      var element = document.getElementById("svg-01"); // Get SVG element.
      SVG2PNG(element, function (canvas) {
        // Arguments: SVG element, callback function.
        var base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // toDataURL return DataURI as Base64 format.
        generateLink("SVG2PNG-01.png", base64).click(); // Trigger the Link is made by Link Generator and download.
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put SVG2PNG in the exported methods object (and indeed you shouldn't, in this case, to be able to access it with just `SVG2PNG()`).

The same goes for `generateLink`.

Instead, you should be fine with just

```
import Canvg from "canvg";

function SVG2PNG(svg, callback) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); // Create a Canvas element.
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // For Canvas returns 2D graphic.
  var data = svg.outerHTML; // Get SVG element as HTML code.
  Canvg(canvas, data); // Render SVG on Canvas.
  callback(canvas); // Execute callback function.
}

function generateLink(fileName, data) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = fileName;
  link.href = data;
  return link;
}

export default {
  methods: {
    tipka() {
      var element = document.getElementById("svg-01"); // Get SVG element.
      SVG2PNG(element, function (canvas) {
        // Arguments: SVG element, callback function.
        var base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // toDataURL return DataURI as Base64 format.
        generateLink("SVG2PNG-01.png", base64).click(); // Trigger the Link is made by Link Generator and download.
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: We tried it and we got two errors, when we put it in our code we get "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function" because the ctx is declared but its value its never read.